# Get specific .childrenCount from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my new app (Project Control, iOS App Store ;)) I want users to take part of development decisions. For this I have added a path in my Firebase database called "claps". I would like to enter the number of the following in my TableView for the different concepts. I have tried the following

```
self.posts.append(Post(title: post_title, des: post_description, info: "\(post_date) - \(post_user) - \(post_claps) ", claps: Int(post_claps)))

for var item in self.posts {

    g.ref.child("concepts").child(item.title).queryOrdered(byChild: "claps").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshotClaps: DataSnapshot!) in

        item.claps = Int(snapshotClaps.childrenCount)

    }

}

DispatchQueue.main.async() {

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

However, it does not yet represent the right one, but is one before it. I don't know how to make the reference more specific to really get only what's under claps.

This ist my Database:

[image: FirebaseDatabase structure]

Currently my output is 5 but it should be 4. You see its observing one "layer" to early. Help will be appreciated. Improvements too :)

**UPDATE:**

Through testing I could reveal that the problem is in the reference. The Int five is coming from the 5 Childs of "top-layer" "Journal". My problem is that I cant get any deeper in the structure because I don't have a specific String for .child()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're observing the `.childAdded` event, your closure gets called for each matching child node. If you want to count the number of matching child nodes, you'll want to observe the `.value` event, which ensures your closure gets called for all matching nodes at once.

Something like:

```
g.ref.child("concepts").child(item.title).observe(.value) { (snapshotClaps: DataSnapshot!) in
    item.claps = Int(snapshotClaps.childrenCount)
}
```

Note that I also removed the `orderBy` clause, since that has no useful meaning if all you use is the count.

Answer (score 3):

create an Array and allow the firebase to populate it. or do something like

```
g.ref.child("concepts").child(item.title).observe(.value) { (snapshotClaps: DataSnapshot!) in
    item.claps = Int(snapshotClaps.childrenCount)
}
```

observing value makes sure your closure gets its matching nodes.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of great solutions but the issue in reading a node by .value is it reads in *everything* in that node.

While that would be fine for nodes that have a limited amount of data, it would overwhelm the device when the node contains a lot of data.

So another option is to leverage that Firebase executes all .childAdded events *before* .value events. That way, we can use a .value as a trigger that all nodes have been read.

Here's a function that uses .childAdded to iterate and count all of the users in the users node. Also, there's a .value observer that reads in just the last node, removes the .childAdded observer and passes the count back to the calling function via a completion handler. Remember that even though we are attaching both observers, the .childAdded events will all fire before the .value event.

```
func countUsers( completion: @escaping(Int) -> Void) {
    var count = 0

    let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")
    usersRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        count+=1
    })

    let query = usersRef.queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toLast: 1)
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        usersRef.removeAllObservers()
        completion(count)
    })
}
```

to call the function, here's the code

```
func getUserCount() {
    self.countUsers(completion: { userCount in
        print("number of users: \(userCount)")
    })
}
```